# How to prefetch web-pages in an WebExtensions add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, prefetch

I would like to pre-fetch the other web-pages linked using a `<a>` (anchor) tag with `rel="prefetch"` in a web-page. So, when user clicks on a such link, I can replace the content of the tab where the link is clicked, with the pre-fetched content. Is it possible to achieve this with WebExtensions?

I thought about downloading the pages in the background using `XMLHttpRequest` and then by listening `onclick` events on anchor tags, replacing the tab's content with `document.write()`. The problem is, I get "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." and I cannot think of any other way.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no simple easy way to do this. There are ways which you might achieve something close to what you desire, but you're basically asking how to write a large portion of the functionality of an extension, for which there would be multiple was to accomplish it depending on *exactly* what you desire. Thus, the question is too broad to cover in the SO format.

Comment: I was thinking of loading web-pages in the background using `XMLHttpRequest`s and then by catching `onclick` events on anchor tags and using `document.write` and history API to `pushState` back. Do you think the question is too broad? The reason I asked was to learn whether WebExtensions provide another (more direct) means to achieve the same end.